# Determine if URI is valid and make it a Valid file on Android for Images

Tags: java, android, uri

I am currently trying to convert all the possible valid URI into a valid File which I can then pipe into Multipart.File and upload to a server.

I have some code I am writing and working with, but there are some cases in which it fails. Also, check out my gist here: https://gist.github.com/mmdock/ed04315851534029f5bc6ea77d6dc6e4

The constraints I am working with are as follows:

1. It has to work with pre-KitKat builds
2. It has to handle real files (we download files from FB or IG)
3. It has to handle document URI
4. It has to handle document remote URI (Google's gallery decides
   autonomously whether to upload the files and only keep thumbs)
5. It has to provide "real" path in the end, meaning the path of the
   file in the apps folder
6. It has to support authority of first, second and third Google Photo
   Gallery generation URI's and Picasa (deprecated by Google, still
   used on some other providers)
7. It has to support content providers
   (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers)

Some references I used to write my code as it currently stands:
https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-get-real-file-path-from-android-uri/

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Accessing-the-Camera-and-Stored-Media

Looking for corrections to my code or hopefully a third party library that doesn't have the same issues as my code has.  I have tried a number of third party libraries (and used them as references for my code), such as :

https://github.com/coltoscosmin/FileUtils/blob/master/FileUtils.java

https://github.com/alhazmy13/MediaPicker/blob/master/libary/src/main/java/net/alhazmy13/mediapicker/FileProcessing.java

https://gist.github.com/alexzaitsev/75c9b36dfcffd545c676

https://github.com/kunpark168/EP/blob/c8cd20504a6696fc35f3e64b4bc79bbadbba76b4/eyeprotec/app/src/main/java/com/uas/eyeprotec/utils/DocumentUtil.java

https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626

https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/blob/master/collect_app/src/main/java/org/odk/collect/android/utilities/MediaUtils.java

https://github.com/Khang-NT/Android-Media-Converter/blob/16f347f7b883f854c400ba7e5ce31db4fdac2740/app/src/main/java/com/github/khangnt/mcp/util/UriUtils.java

https://github.com/esafirm/android-image-picker/blob/master/imagepicker/src/main/java/com/esafirm/imagepicker/features/ImageFileLoader.java

https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage/blob/master/library/src/main/java/pl/aprilapps/easyphotopicker/EasyImage.java

Sorry for the large number of link.  Been working on getting this corrected for awhile.

Comment: The only more-or-less valid code there is `copyContentToTempFile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare what do you mean?

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file. If you want a file, do what you are doing in `copyContentToTempFile()`, and copy the content to a file that you control. Everything else that you are doing makes tons of assumptions, ones that may be invalid based on OS version, device firmware changes, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, this is what literally every lib does if you check out the links, more or less.  Converting from a URI to usable file is an incredibly hard task on Android apparently.

Comment: Not really. You have the code for it in `copyContentToTempFile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare it doesn't work in many cases, hence why I am working on this.

Comment: "it doesn't work in many cases" -- opening an `InputStream` and copying the bytes to a file should work in all cases, assuming you do so while you still have rights to access the content. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question showing the `copyContentToTempFile()` code and explain **in detail** what "it doesn't work in many cases" means.